# Followed by Instagram API request

Tags: instagram-api

I'm attempting to request the information from Instagram of my followers.

I'm getting a 200 code but no information. Not having this problem with any other requests relating to user or media, just followers. Is there something obvious I am missing?

```
{
pagination: { },
meta: {
code: 200
},
data: [ ]
}
```

Comment: Hey it would be helpful to see the code you're using to connect to the api / make the request. Can't offer much help without seeing what you have done, what isn't working and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Im just using a http request to  https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN but with an access token. I presume the access token is not the problem given the 200 code

Comment: Do you know that Instagram updated there api process ?   http://instagram.com/developer